# Connection Reset Error after quitting Selenium ChromeDriver despite matching versions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium is giving me a ConnectionReset error after I quit the driver

My code looks something like this

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
try {
     // main code here
     System.out.println("success");
}
catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
     System.out.println("quitting");
     driver.quit();
}
```

And produces this output

```html
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 01, 2022 7:13:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Aug 01, 2022 7:13:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 103
success
quitting
Aug 01, 2022 7:13:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

It says that it `Found exact CDP implementation for version 103` so why is it producing this error?

Comment: _SocketError_: Some more error tracelog please.

Comment: alright i fixed it